# Emacs calling align regexp

Tags: regex, function, emacs, alignment

I am trying to pass arguments to the align-regexp function in Emacs (Lisp):

```
(defun align-on-comment-char ()
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "#")
)
```

I would actually like to do this for all my modes specifically, where for each mode I want to bind an "align to comment character (`;` for emacs lisp, `%` for Latex, `#` for R)".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`comment-start` and `comment-end` are the usual variables to get the comment-string for the current mode.

You will also need to append some magic to get the matching right when
calling align-regexp. Like Oleg, I had to figure that out the hard way
by looking at the source. The error message here is not really
descriptive and I really consider this worthy of a bug-report or at
least a doc fix.

```
(defun align-comment (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)" comment-start))
)
```

Comment: Please elaborate. My goal is to align a region (selected text) on the comment character for that mode. I'm fine with having functions for each mode specifically. Let's try first this one with the # character?

Comment: @Dualinity OK, this was really more tricky than I expected. I have posted a full working example.

Comment: Excellent! Props to you. Kind of gave me hope, since I really tried my best as a Emacs Lisp novice.

Comment: I am curious though, the arguments beg and end are coming from the (interactive "r") statement?

Comment: @Dualinity Yes, it's a feature of interactive. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html and especially the next page http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes which contains all codes.

Comment: these manuals never feel complete and are somehow never doing it for me. do you know another way to learn more about (let), (concat) and that kind of things?

Comment: oh and btw, do you use a function like this one yourself? why (not)?

Comment: @Dualinity The function looks sensible. If you use it, have it. No dogma. I usually just define stuff like that on the fly when I need it. For the manual: The elisp manual itself is really not good (the functionality documentation (<kdb>C-h f</kdb>)) usually is. Pick up a lisp book for a more general introduction or start with some of Xah Lee's tutorials. http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp.html

Comment: @Dualinity The elisp manual is a reference book, not a tutorial. It's great for details when you already have the general idea. For novices, http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/ is a great introduction, and is available from the Emacs info system. Then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp

Answer (score 4):

You should change your code a little bit.

For example like this:

```
(defun align-on-comment-char (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end "\\(\\s-*\\)#")
)
```

A magic string `"\\(\\s-*\\)"` is taken from the sources of `align-regexp`.

If you want to have a single function for all modes then use `comment-start` variable as @pmr pointed out.

```
(align-regexp beg end (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)" comment-start))
```

Comment: I saw that about the same string about the time you posted. This really needs better documentation.

Comment: Well, it's not a "magic string"; it's simply the specified regexp group to modify in the alignment process. It just happens that a zero-or-more-whitespace group is what you'll want to use most of the time. I do agree that the alignment system could do with some documentation improvements.